# devexpress progress bar performstep method not showing

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

i need to upload records from excel sheet to sql server
while uploading i need to show the progress in devexpress progress bar 
and that too in a manner like uploading 1 out of 100 and it should increment until it finishes

Comment: I would suggest the use of a MarqueeProgressBasrControl instead. When using the progressbar control you'll need to know the amount of rows. Some files may be large.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a [**BackgroundWorker**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) and report progress back to the main GUI Thread. Then update the progress bar value with the status coming from the BackgroundWorker.

Here is an example, it uses a common WinForms ProgressBar instead of a DevExpress ProgressBar but the principle is just the same.

```
public partial class Progress : Form
{
    readonly BackgroundWorker _worker = new BackgroundWorker();

    public Progress()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        _worker.DoWork += _worker_DoWork;
        _worker.ProgressChanged += WorkerProgressChanged;
        _worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerRunWorkerCompleted;

        _worker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }


    private void _worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        // Simulate work (uploading Excel records to SQL Server)
        for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            if (worker.CancellationPending)
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
                break;
            }

            // Upload some data here, Sleep(100) is just an example
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            // Calculate current progress and report
            worker.ReportProgress(i);
        }
    }

    void WorkerProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        _progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

    void WorkerRunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        _progressBar.Value = 0;
    }
}
```